# alocação dinamica de matriz dentro de uma struct

Tags: c, struct, alocação

enunciado e codigo:

> Faca um programa que armazena filmes produzidos por varios diretores
>   e:
>       - Crie e leia um vetor de 5 diretores, cada um contendo nome (maximo 20 letras), quantidade de filmes
>       e filmes. O membro filmes é um vetor, que deve ser criado apos ter lido a quantidade de filmes. Cada
>       filme é composto por nome, ano e duracao.
>       - Procure um diretor por nome, mostrando todos os filmes que ele ja produziu. Repita o processo
>       ate digitar uma string vazia.

```
#define QTD 2

typedef struct diretor {
    char nome[20], **filme;
    int qtd;
} DIRETOR;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    DIRETOR diretor[QTD];
    char busca[20];

    for (int i=0; i<QTD; i++) {
        printf("Nome do diretor: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(diretor[i].nome, 20, stdin);
        diretor[i].nome[strlen(diretor[i].nome) -1] = '\0';

        printf("Quantidade de filmes: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &diretor[i].qtd);

        while (isalpha(diretor[i].qtd) != 0) {
           printf("Entre com um número válido.\n");
           printf("Quantidade de filmes: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &diretor[i].qtd);
       }

       diretor[i].filme = (char **) malloc(sizeof(DIRETOR) * diretor[i].qtd);
        for (int l=0; l<QTD; l++) diretor[i].filme[i] = (char*) malloc (20 * sizeof(DIRETOR));

        for (int j=0; j<diretor[i].qtd; j++) {
            printf("Filme %d:", j+1);
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(diretor[i].filme[j], 20, stdin);
            diretor[i].filme[j][strlen(diretor[i].filme[j]) -1] = '\0';
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    do {
        printf("Diretor que deseja buscar: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(busca, 20, stdin);
        busca[strlen(busca) -1] = '\0';

        for (int i=0; i<QTD; i++) {
            if (strcmpi(busca, diretor[i].nome) == 0 && strcmp(busca , "") != 0) {
                printf("Filmes:\n");
                for(int j=0; j<diretor[i].qtd; j++)
                    printf("%s\n", diretor[i].filme[j]);
            }
        }
    } while (strcmp(busca , "") != 0) ;
}
```

minha duvida é: estou alocando a matriz corretamente?

pois ele não funciona quando tento colocar mais de 2 filmes no mesmo diretor!
desde ja, obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> minha duvida é: estou alocando a matriz corretamente?

Nem por isso. A alocação foi feita com base no tamanho de `DIRETOR`, alocando um vetor de `DIRETORES` mas o tipo de `filme` é `char**`:

```
diretor[i].filme = (char **) malloc(sizeof(DIRETOR) * diretor[i].qtd);
//                       ^---- tipo            ^---- tamanho alocado de cada elemento
```

Ou seja alocou um vetor de diretores e guardou num duplo ponteiro de char, e por isso os tipos e tamanhos não jogam. Se a sua matriz é uma matriz de `char**` para guardar *strings* declarada na forma de `char **filme` então a alocação correta seria:

```
diretor[i].filme = malloc(sizeof(char *) * diretor[i].qtd);
//                                  ^----
```

Note que omiti o *cast* pois ele não é obrigatório. Devo também acrescentar que chamar ao campo `filmes` seria bem mais claro do que representa, em vez de `filme`.

Mas não posso deixar de dizer que isso não responde ao enunciado. O enunciado diz claramente que:

> Cada filme é composto por nome, ano e duracao

Então `filme` devia ser uma estrutura:

```
typedef struct filme {
   char nome[50];
   int ano, duracao;
} FILME;
```

E agora seria esta a estrutura usada dentro de `DIRETOR`:

```
typedef struct diretor {
    char nome[20];
    FILME *filmes; // <--- vetor dinâmico de filmes
    int qtd;
} DIRETOR;
```

A alocação passaria agora a ser:

```
diretor[i].filmes = malloc(sizeof(FILME) * diretor[i].qtd);
```

Agora fica a faltar ajustar o código que sobra para esta nova estrutura de filmes.